# unexpectected token } on line 26 but there is no } on line 26 ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hi all I'm new to javascript and I'm working my way through "Learning Javascript" by Tim Wright. I'm trying to use JSON.parse to convert from a string but when I run the code I get an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } on line 26 but I can't see a } on line 26. I tried copying and pasting the code from the pdf to see if I've done something wrong but it still gives the same error.

```
//create an instance of the xmlhttrequest

function getHTTPObject() {

    //initialize the variable
    var xhr;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xhr;
}//end getHTTPObject

function ajaxCall(dataUrl, callback) {

    var request = getHTTPObject();


    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

            var contacts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            if(typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(contacts);
            }//end function check
        }//end ajax status check

    } //end onreadystatechange
    request.open("GET", dataUrl, true);     
    request.send(null);
}




ajaxCall('data/contacts.json');
```

I know I'm probably just missing something really obvious but I just can't see it. Thanks for the help.

update here's what my json file looks like:

```
{  "addressBook" : [


    {
        "name": "Elysha",
        "email":"elysha@gmail.com",
    },

    {
        "name": "Luke",
        "email":"lukerobingregory@gmail.com",
    },

    {
        "name": "Dad",
        "email":"dad@gmail.com",
    },

    {
        "name": "Mum",
        "email":"mum@gmail.com",
    }



]
```

}

Comment: Tell us which line is line 26.

Comment: @user2609980: `request.responseText`, presumably.

Comment: Your code as shown does not seem to contain any syntax errors. More likely, the message is about the value your server-side script returns – that can’t be parsed as JSON because it contains errors.

Comment: My guess is that line 26 is `JSON.parse(request.responseText)`, and the syntax error is in the JSON.

Comment: Can you show us your returned, expected, JSON? - perhaps do a `console.log(request.responseText)` - just before your `var contacts = ...` line

Comment: Interesting, those `} // comment here` lines break http://jsbeautifier.org...

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368882/unexpected-tokens-in-js-trying-to-learn-ajax?rq=1

Comment: Same problem, different code, @PatrickW.McMahon. That answer will not help here.

Comment: A trailing comma in the "string"?

Comment: I think the problem is with my json because I linked to a different file http://jsbin.com/fepejidiyisa/3/edit provided by an answerer but I can't seem to see his comment since updating the question with my json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trailing comma in the JSON string:

```
{
    "name": "Mum",
    "email":"mum@gmail.com",
}                          ^-- remove this comma, and corresponding commas in all the other "objects".
```

Though you can have a trailling comma in JS object literal, it is not allowed in JSON syntax.

Comment: Thankyou it wasn't just that comma I added an extra comma to every item